# VS Code API: Is there a function to find how many indentation rulers exists in a line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-api

For instance:
Given the following python code

- Lines `2`,`3`,`4`,`5` have only 1 indentation ruler
- Line `6` have 2 indentation rulers
- Lines `7`,`8` have 3 indentation rulers
- Lines `1`,`9`,`10`,`11` have no indentation ruler at all

[image]

##### Is there a function in VS Code API that gets this information?

The purpose is to use in an extension

Comment: No api for that directly.  You would have to count the number of tabs on each line (or spaces if that is used for indentation - which means checking the settings for that value).  What are you planning on using that information for?

Comment: @Mark, I'm afraid not: line 7 does not have any tab or spaces (it is an empty line), and still have 3 indentation lines.